# CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

Tags: ios, iphone, react-native

I'm getting following error in react native application for iOS.

```
Installing build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Este.app
    An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):
    Failed to install the requested application
    An application bundle was not found at the provided path.
    Provide a valid path to the desired application bundle.
    Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist

    Command failed: /usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c Print:CFBundleIdentifier build/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Este.app/Info.plist
    Print: Entry, ":CFBundleIdentifier", Does Not Exist
```

But I see Info.plist has CFBundleIdentifier as below.

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>org.reactjs.native.example.$(PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier)</string>
```

I also tried changing the above to

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
 <string>com.myApp</string>
```

but same error. Please help.

I also see the following error displayed before the above error

```
node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/ios/RCTFBSDK/share/RCTFBSDKShareDialog.h:21:9: fatal error: 
      'FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h' file not found
#import <FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h>
```

Answer (score -4, accepted):

The problem is solved after put the facebook rnfbsdk frameworks in ~/documents/ folder.

Comment: I think this answer is incomplete

Answer (score 5):

After losing my time with this error, I found the solution, the problem is in pods, it may be that when updating some library, pods are not synchronized.

**My solution:**
Go to /ios folder ----> and run the command: 
·

> pod install && pod update

- after go back to the project folder ----> and run the command: 
  ·

> rm -rf node_modules && npm install

Clean ios build folder:
·

> rm -rf ios/build

After that, just run as usual:
·

> react-native run-ios

Answer (score 2):

you can try changing it to $(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)

Comment: I have this value set. How exactly does `$(foo)` work? perhaps I need to set that environment value elsewhere?